# Is the recommendation of other team members is as valuable as CTOs?

Tags: interviewing, recommendation-letter

I left my previous company. On the last day, the CTO told me that she can give me a recommendation, and help me to find a new employer.

But, later I figured out that when I give a her as a reference in my CV, she says negative things about me.

So, I cannot consider her as a reference, but I know the other teammates will highlight my positive points for employers.

But, the question is:

- Is the recommendation of another team member as valuable as CTOs?
- How would the HRs react if the recommendation does not come from a manager?

Comment: Apart from spite, or if you did something really, really, really bad, why did the CTO offer to be your reference if she only has negative things to say about you? How would your colleagues contradict the CTO?

Comment: @Kozaky i got lay off because of economical situation in the company. The CTO layed me off `without a notice`. She offered me 1 month more salary to compensation, but i figured out the law says, the compensation is `2 month`. So, i took a lawyer against the company. I think, this is the main reason. I did not do anything bad. I just stood up for my rights, and i will always rise again in future.

Comment: @SalmanLashkarara Did you take the lawyer **after** the CTO told you she can give you recommendation?

Comment: @Kepotx no, it was before. At the end, i got the `2 month` compensation, and i tried to leave them friendly, but i think, she fools me, and betrayed me, to take a revenge, just because of 1 more month salary.

Comment: Your English is a bit hard to understand. Did she send a bad reference to some company, or do you just suspect she would send a bad reference?

Comment: Your English is unclear. Which one is true : you have evidence that she did send a bad reference. Or you suspect that she did send a bad reference. Or you suspect that she will send a bad reference. It seems you have just a suspicion that she will act totally unprofessional and take revenge on you for getting money that doesn’t come out of her pocket.

Comment: @gnasher729 The correct statement is: `I have evidence that she did send a bad reference.` After, i left the former company, i joined a new company. And my new employer told me, my previous employer wrote negative things about me. As a result, although they hired me, they were very negative about me, and i left the second company as well. please read this question:https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/126761/can-i-ask-hr-to-put-me-on-a-pip

Comment: Your former CTO sounds like a total @sshole. I'm glad you at least get out of her office.

Comment: That's very unprofessional of her. If there was anything untrue in her reference you could sue her for having cost you the new job.

Answer (score 3):

> Is the recommendation of another team member as valuable as CTOs?

No.

But a good reference from another team member is more valuable than a bad reference from a CTO.

> How would the HRs react if the recommendation does not come from a
>   manager?

Recommendations from managers are better. But those from non-managers are good too. And sometimes you don't really have a choice.

In general, for references always use only people who will say wonderful things about you.

Answer (score 3):

All things are relative...

CTO: This person was incompetent and among the first we let go when we had a cash flow problem. Would never even consider rehiring.

Teammate: Was the best and most competent person on the team.  Would love to work with them again.

Vs

CTO: This person was extremely valuable and competent, saddened to see them go. Would rehire in a heartbeat if I could.

Teammate: Worst teammate ever.  Would quit rather than work with them again.

Regardless of any ranking, you should only use references that you are confident will say good things about you.  It is better to have no reference than a bad reference.